# ASP.NET MVC Base Controller Function not firing when I need it to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I'm noticing some behavior that I don't like, and I'm wondering if this is normal.

I've got a BaseController that is Inheriting from Mvc.Controller, and I've got a View function inside that is to fire on every page load.

```
Protected Overrides Function View(ByVal viewName As String, ByVal masterName As String, ByVal model As Object) As System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult


    If Session("UserInfo") Is Nothing AndAlso User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Try
            ActivityMonitorService.AddActivity(UserService.GetUserByOpenID(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).ID, _
                                               Utilities.ActivityMonitor.Log.SessionStarted, _
                                               Utilities.DataConverters.IPAddressToNumber(HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress))
            ActivityMonitorService.SubmitChanges()
        Catch : End Try
        Session("UserInfo") = UserService.GetUserByOpenID(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
    End If

End Function
```

The Problem I have is if the Session state is closed, I get an Object Reference error on this function

```
Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
    If DirectCast(Session("UserInfo"), Domain.User).ID = id Then

        Dim user As Domain.User = UserService.GetUserByID(id)
        Return View(user)

    Else
        Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        Return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error")
    End If
End Function
```

Now I'm assuming it is because the Base Function `View` is actually firing on `Return View(user)`.  If this is true, how would I wire it up to fire an event on ever `ActionResult` Call?

## EDIT:

It does appear to work however if I put the code here

```
Protected Overrides Function CreateActionInvoker() As System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker
    If Session("UserInfo") Is Nothing AndAlso User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Try
            ActivityMonitorService.AddActivity(UserService.GetUserByOpenID(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).ID, _
                                               Utilities.ActivityMonitor.Log.SessionStarted, _
                                               Utilities.DataConverters.IPAddressToNumber(HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress))
            ActivityMonitorService.SubmitChanges()
        Catch : End Try
        Session("UserInfo") = UserService.GetUserByOpenID(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
    End If
    Return MyBase.CreateActionInvoker()
End Function
```

Is this the right place to put the Session State "stuff"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to mark this as answer with the solution in my Edit

```
Protected Overrides Function CreateActionInvoker() As System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker
    If Session("UserInfo") Is Nothing AndAlso User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Try
            ActivityMonitorService.AddActivity(UserService.GetUserByOpenID(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).ID, _
                                               Utilities.ActivityMonitor.Log.SessionStarted, _
                                               Utilities.DataConverters.IPAddressToNumber(HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress))
            ActivityMonitorService.SubmitChanges()
        Catch : End Try
        Session("UserInfo") = UserService.GetUserByOpenID(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
    End If
    Return MyBase.CreateActionInvoker()
End Function
```